# Most computationally efficient method to perform sumproduct for a very large dataframe in R

Tags: r, performance

I have a very large dataframe (hundreds of columns and tens of thousands of rows) for which I would like to do the following:

- on each row calculate weighted combinations of the elements on the column using given vector(s) of weights (some of the weights may be zero)
- create a new dataframe with each of the columns containing the weighted combinations for the corresponding vector of weights

What would be the most computationally efficient way to do that?

Replicating simple example:

```
require(tidyverse)

theDatesTibble <-c(lubridate::mdy("3/15/2017"), lubridate::mdy("4/15/2017"), lubridate::mdy("5/15/2017"), lubridate::mdy("6/15/2017"))

theValuesTibble_A <- c(123.45, 201.29, 337.78, 275.98)
theValuesTibble_B <- c(113.45, 221.29, 327.78, 255.98)
theValuesTibble_C <- c(143.45, 251.29, 307.78, 235.98)
theValuesTibble_D <- c(153.45, 231.29, 347.78, 225.98)
theValuesTibble_E <- c(163.45, 291.29, 323.78, 215.98)

theTibble <- tibble(Dates= theDatesTibble, A = theValuesTibble_A, B = theValuesTibble_B, 
                    C = theValuesTibble_C, D = theValuesTibble_D, E = theValuesTibble_E)

weights_1 <- c(2.3, 0.0, 3.6, 12.7, 8.9)
weights_2 <- c(0.0, 0.0, 13.6, 4.7, 0.0)
weights_3 <- c(6.3, 4.4, 8.6, 12.3, 18.9)
```

Comment: Looks like matrix products to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BenoitLondon mentioned, a matrix product would be the fastest way to do what you want.

```
cbind.data.frame(
  theTibble[1],
  as.matrix(theTibble[-1]) %*% cbind(weights_1, weights_2, weights_3)
)
```